# Plotting Bar Charts with Bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to plot a basic barchart but I keep seeing an error called 'StopIteration'. I am following an example, and the code seems fine:

```
amount = bugrlary_dict.values()
months = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]

print len(amount)
print len(months)
bar = Bar(amount, months, filename="bar.html")

bar.title("Bar Chart of the Amount of Burglaries").xlabel("Months").ylabel("Amount")
bar.show()
```

Comment: You're getting an error but everything seems fine, does that mean the plot is still appearing? Is `StopIteration` the only think you get or is there more to it?

Comment: meaning, the code seems fine. No plot is shown. I will edit that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***UPDATE*** *this answer is out of date and will not work with Bokeh versions newer than `0.10`*

Please refer to [recent documentation](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/charts.html)

---

---

You're passing invalid input. From the [doc](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.10.0/docs/reference/charts.html):

> (dict, OrderedDict, lists, arrays and DataFrames are valid inputs)

This is the example they have on there:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from bokeh.charts import Bar, output_file, show

# (dict, OrderedDict, lists, arrays and DataFrames are valid inputs)
xyvalues = OrderedDict()
xyvalues['python']=[-2, 5]
xyvalues['pypy']=[12, 40]
xyvalues['jython']=[22, 30]

cat = ['1st', '2nd']

bar = Bar(xyvalues, cat, title="Stacked bars",
        xlabel="category", ylabel="language")

output_file("stacked_bar.html")
show(bar)
```

Your `amount` is a `dict_values()` which will not be accepted. I'm not sure what your `bugrlary_dict` is but have that as the `data` for the `Bar()` and I'm assuming your `months` is the label. That should work assuming `len(bugrlary_dict) == 12`

Output from Bokeh's example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In [Bokeh 0.12.5](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/charts.html#bar), you can do it the following way:

```
from bokeh.charts import Bar, output_file, show

# best support is with data in a format that is table-like
data = {
    'sample': ['1st', '2nd', '1st', '2nd', '1st', '2nd'],
    'interpreter': ['python', 'python', 'pypy', 'pypy', 'jython', 'jython'],
    'timing': [-2, 5, 12, 40, 22, 30]
}

# x-axis labels pulled from the interpreter column, grouping labels from sample column
bar = Bar(data, values='timing', label='sample', group='interpreter',
      title="Python Interpreter Sampling - Grouped Bar chart",
      legend='top_left', plot_width=400, xlabel="Category", ylabel="Language")

output_file("grouped_bar.html")
show(bar)
```

Output:

[image]

**Change the parameter in `Bar()` from `group` to `stack` if you want a stacked bar chart**